# How can I discard changes to unstaged files using magit?

Tags: magit, git

Is there a way to issue the command:

> git checkout NameOfFile

on a modified and unstaged file from within MAGIT?

Comment: You can press `k` to kill the changes when point is on the same line with the unstaged file.

Comment: Try `x` when hovering a hunk in spacemacs.

Comment: @moritzschaefer There is no indication that this question applies to spacemacs.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use one of the below to discard changes in unstaged files:

- `M-x magit-revert-item` (bound to `v` in `magit-status-mode`)
- `M-x magit-discard-item` (bound to `k` in `magit-status-mode`) - **works on staged items too**

Using either method will ask you to confirm before discarding.

Comment: You can also use `k` which is bound to `magit-discard-item` in `magit-mode`.

Comment: Yes, that works too.

Comment: Tried using both methods, however I still receive the message: "Nothing to discard here".

Comment: thanks! Magit-mode seems like the best way to do just about everything I've found...

Comment: @user2522280 Have you saved your file? `git status` should give you information that the file has been modified.

Comment: Is there any way, so I can discard all unstaged changes?

Comment: Try pressing  `k` on `Unstage changes (<n>)` (where <n> is the number of unstage changes you have).

Comment: What's incredible is that `k` and `v` also work on local changes inside a file! You can thus reverse some changes and keep the others in the same file. Magit rocks \o/

Comment: I found that `M-x magit-revert-item` only worked for staged changes, whereas `M-x magit-discard-item` allowed me to discard changes in un-staged items

Comment: In newer versions of magit these are called simply `magit-discard` and `magit-revert`.

Comment: Magit has changed since this answer was written so now only `k` works.

Answer (score 20):

Reversing, reverting and discarding are distinct actions. Together with staging and unstaging, they are referred to as "apply variants".

To *discard* a change means to throw it away. Only un-committed changes can be discarded. When a staged change is discarded it is not only removed from the index (that is known as unstaging), but also from the work tree.

To *reverse* a change means to apply it to the work tree in reverse. Both committed and merely staged changes can be reversed. (Reversing staged changes is actually useful, i.e. when splitting up a commit).

Only commits can be *reverted*, in other regards it's similar to *reversing*.

See https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/History-Manipulation for details.

Comment: "Reverting staged changes..." - you meant "Rever**s**ing staged changes..." I guess

Comment: Yes. Common mistake because this distinction is not as clear as the other :-)